# Laravel _ Lockout the account after 5 consecutive failed logins in api

Tags: php, laravel, api

I am developing a mobile app using laravel. I am login in using the api. In it, I want to block a user account after 5 consecutive failed logins. How can I do that? Please help.

Thank you

Comment: Please try posting what you have already attempted and what your exact issue is. While we are more than happy to help, StackOverflow is not a project completion site.

Answer (score 0):

```
  public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('throttle:5,1')->only('login'); 
    }
```

you can use middleware throttle only for login if user attempt 5 failed login in a minute then it will lock the account

Comment: Thanks for your reply.                                                        
The solution you gave can use in Login controller of Laravel.(only if we use default laravel authentication ) Is it?                                                                       
 But we are using the user-defined APIs for register and login.  How we can write code to block the user depending on ip address and number of attempts (attempts: max 5 )

Comment: you can make a column in user table name as failedAttempts and increment it with +1 on each attempt on successful login reset it to 0 and on fail increment and then make a if condition to check if  failedAttempts==5 then block the user

Answer (score 0):

> My laravel version: 8 and Authentication package: sanctum
>
> VIMP: I hope you have installed the Larvel sanctum package

You can try this code

Step 1: install the laravel ui package [I don't know why the 'ThrottlesLogins' trait requires this.]

```
composer require laravel/ui
```

Step 2: Now we have to include a trait to handle the login attempts

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ThrottlesLogins;
```

Step 3: Now declare the maxAttempts, decayMinutes as global variables

```
 protected $decayMinutes = 2; // In minutes
 protected $warning = 3; // In minutes
```

Step 4: Now create your login method

Example, LoginController.php

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ThrottlesLogins;  // include the trait
use Illuminate\Support\Str; // to customize the throttle key

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    use ThrottlesLogins; // use the trait
    protected  $maxAttempts = 5;
    protected $decayMinutes = 2; // In minutes
    protected $warning = 3; // Where we should show the warning message (attempts count)

    
    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        if ($this->hasTooManyLoginAttempts($request)) { // checking form maximum login attempts
            return $this->prepareLockMessage($request); // to customize the  message, you can use the below-commented default method
            //return $this->sendLockoutResponse($request); // laravel own response
        }
        try {
            $credentials            = request(['email', 'password']);
            if (!Auth::attempt($credentials)) {                 // login failed
                $this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);        // increment the attempt count
                
                if ($this->hasTooManyLoginAttempts($request)) { // checking form maximum login attempts
                    return $this->prepareLockMessage($request);
                  
                } else {
                    $attempts_count = $this->limiter()->attempts($this->throttleKey($request)); // number of attempts performed
                    $message = "The email or password you have entered is incorrect.";
                    if($attempts_count >= $this->warning) {         // before locking adding a warning message. 'warning' variable will handle this
                        $remaining = $this->maxAttempts-$attempts_count;    // number of attempts left
                        $message .="Your account will be blocked after ".($remaining)." failed attempts.";
                    }
                    return $message;
                }
            }
            $user                   = User::where('email', $request->email)->first();
            if ( ! Hash::check($request->password, $user->password, [])) {
                throw new \Exception('Error in Login');
            }

            $this->clearLoginAttempts($request); // for the successful login clearing the attempts count

            $tokenResult            = $user->createToken('authToken')->plainTextToken;
            return response()->json([
                'status'            => true,
                'access_token'      => $tokenResult,
                'token_type'        => 'Bearer',
            ]);
        
        } catch(\Exception $e) {
            return response()->json([
                'status'        => false,
                'message'       => "something went wrong."
            ],422);
        }
    }

/**
    * To specify the login username to be used.
    *
    * @return string
*/
public function username()
{
    return 'email';
}

/**
 * Convert seconds to minute:seconds.
 */
public function ToMinutes($seconds=0) {
    $minutes = 0;
    if($seconds > 0) {
        return gmdate("i:s", $seconds);
        //$minutes = intval($seconds/60);
    }
    return $minutes;
}

// To customize the lock message
public function prepareLockMessage($request)
{
    try {
        $this->fireLockoutEvent($request);          // checking the locking event
        $seconds = $this->limiter()->availableIn(   // reading how much seconds user should wait
            $this->throttleKey($request)
        );
        if($seconds < 60) {                         // processing the remaining seconds - start
            $minutes = $seconds;                    // a few seconds are remaining
            $timer = "seconds";
        } else {
            $minutes = $this->ToMinutes($seconds);  // converting the seconds into minutes
            $timer = "minutes";
        }
        return "Your account has been blocked. Please wait for ".$minutes." ".$timer.".";

    } catch (\Throwable $th) {
        throw $th;
    }
}

/**
 * Customizing throttle key, use if needed
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return string
 */
protected function throttleKey(Request $request)
{
    return Str::transliterate(Str::lower($request->input($this->username())).'|'.$request->ip());
}
```